# use regular expression in case statements

Tags: regex, sas

I try to use regular expression in case statements in SAS as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table lib_name.CIS_Ser_flat_Info as
select NO, company, 
       case when prxmatch(prxparse("^(map)|^(mb\s?person)"), upper(company))>0 then 1 else 0 end as map_flag,
from map_info;
quit;
```

But is still shows the problem as follows:

> Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, (, *, **, +,
>   ',', -, /, <, <=, 
>                 <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, FROM, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, 
>                 LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.

The table looks like:

```
No company
1  saura
2  maybe
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code.

For starters, `upper()` is not a SAS function. If you're trying to convert the value of `company` to uppercase, the function is `upcase()`.

Secondly, regular expression patterns must start and end with slashes `/`.

Lastly, you don't need to use `prxparse()` within `prxmatch`.

The following should do what you want:

```
proc sql;
create table lib_name.CIS_Ser_flat_Info as
select NO, company, 
       case when prxmatch("/^(map)|^(mb\s?person)/", upcase(company)) then 1 else 0 end as map_flag,
from map_info;
quit;
```

Comment: This is logical error instead of a syntactical one: the regex would produce no match because `company` is `upcase`d. So either make the regex case insensitive with `/^(map)|^(mb\s?person)/i` or `lowcase(company)`

Comment: ...or just `company` without a case function nor an `i` modifier on the regex. While the two entries in his example are lowercase, the actual data (and his use case) could be case-sensitive.

Comment: right, I'm just pointing it out since the use of `upper` in OP's question implies that he wants it to be case insensitive.

Comment: the use of `upper` in OP's question suggest he wants his regex to never match ;) But you're right, I failed to see that.